# Remove styles set on specific event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm looking for a way to automatically remove styles set on specific event. Maybe I have ust overlooked it, but I have not seen such a feature in jQuery or vanilla js.

The idea:

```
$(element).hover(function() {
    $(this).css({
        backgroundColor : 'red',
        color : 'white'
    });
}, function() {
    // remove styles set on handlerIn()
}).mousedown(function() {
    $(this).css({
        paddingTop : '+=1px',
        paddingBottom : '-=1px'
    });
}).mouseup(function() {
    // remove styles set on mousedown
});
```

If I'm using `$(this).removeAttr('style');` it will remove not only the styles set by specific event, but everything - where with `mousedown` / `mouseup`, that would remove the styles set by `hover`.

And yes, I know I can hardcode the values back to the defaults - doesn't fit!

What would be the best way to achieve such functionality?

Answer (score 1):

You can do one thing for this. Declare classes for hover and unhover, something like:

```
.hover {padding: 5px;}
.unhover {padding: 0px;}
```

Then you can use `.addClass('hover').removeClass('unhover')` and the ilk. BTW, this is valid only if you have absolute properties.

Comment: That removes all the necessity for a script, because I could apply my harcoded properties to `:hover`, `:active` pseudo classes.

Comment: yeah, thats what I said... But, some way is to have them stored in a location like `data-style=""` and access it using jQuery's `attr()` and try?

Comment: That way you'd want to access them with `data()` not `attr()`, and it's even more hassle than A.K's answer suggests.

Comment: @psycketom: Updated my answer by using arrays. I think it will not be a hassle anymore.

Answer (score 1):

#### EDITED

If you are feasible using arrays then see this **solution**.

```
var cssArray = [
    {'background-color':'red','color':'white'},
    {'background-color':'','color':''},    
    {'paddingTop':'+=10px','paddingBottom':'+=10px'},
    {'paddingTop':'','paddingBottom':''}    
]

$('div').hover(function() {
    $(this).css(
        cssArray[0]
    );
}, function() {
    $(this).css(
        cssArray[1]
    ); 
}).mousedown(function() {
    $(this).css(
       cssArray[2]
    );
}).mouseup(function() {
    $(this).css(
       cssArray[3]
    );
});​
```

### [SEE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/akhurshid/gZGQh/)

Comment: Yes, this works, but it still requires to define every property needed to be reset. And if there are 10+ values that have been set, this becomes more than a hassle.

Comment: Even here you are hardcoding something... Right?

Comment: @psycketom: Updated my answer by using arrays. I think it will not be a hassle anymore.

Comment: Please, do not add multiple comments. Anyways, this has the same problem - **explicitly defined properties to be reset**, just a little abstractized. Now, how would I go with this if I had to apply this to 6 different elements each having different styles?

Answer (score 1):

You can declare multiple class on your css and add or remove them

```
 $(element).hover(function() {
    $(this).addClass("classHandlerIn");
 }, function() {
    $(this).removeClass("classHandlerIn").addClass("classHandlerOut")
 }).mousedown(function() {
    $(this).addClass("classMouseDown");
 }).mouseup(function() {
    $(this).removeClass("classMouseDown");
 });
```

Hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

First of all there is no `$(element)` selector.

You can create classes and gave them css properties and use with jQuery `addClass()` and `removeClass()` methods for removning specific event.

Note that [`bind()`](http://api.jquery.com/bind/) method is much more solid instead of `hover()`. [Here is working jsFiddle:](http://jsfiddle.net/dmYth/15/)

```
$('#element').bind({
    mouseenter :function() {
        $(this).css({
            'background-color': 'red',
            'color': 'white'
        });
    },
    mouseleave: function() {
       $(this).css({
        'background-color': 'white',
        'color': 'black'
       });
    },
    mousedown: function() {
        $(this).css({
            paddingTop : '+=10px'
        });
    },
    mouseup: function() {
        $(this).css({
            paddingTop : '-=10px'
        });
    }
});​
```

And don't forgot to use **CSS Pseudo-classes** like `:hover` and `:active` selectors. [Here link for all of them.](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_pseudo_classes.asp)

Comment: `bind()` doesn't make any difference in here, the problem still persists, I have to explicitly reset every property I have set. About pseudo-classes, I have not forgotten about them - that's why I'm writing a script; CSS lacks `+=`, `-=` or any other calculations. And I'm looking to combine this script with jQuery Color plugin for `saturation` / `lightness` &/ other color manipulations. About `$(element)` - assume it's an imaginary variable with value typeof DOMNode.

Comment: bind() won't solve this problem but, using it is much more solid way to go and as your problem i suggested addClass and removeClass methods ? Did you see that? **why -1 ?**

Comment: `addClass()` / `removeClass()` was already suggested by Praveen.

Comment: I didn't see that answer, while working on mine. So thats why you gave me **-1** for trying to help you. Okay.